# Using .find for multiple strings VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use `.find` for more than one string at a time? For example,

worksheet.find(What:="String1", "String1", "String3", etc...)

It doesn't work now, because it's expecting the `After` parameter, but I need to check the sheet for a certain set of strings to accurately determine the number of rows I need to read through (my macro grabs data from a workbook and posts it into another workbook).

I know I could always just use a giant `If Or` statement and loop through all the rows and columns, I just figured using `.find` would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Do you want the first cell that contains **any** of the strings or do you want the full set of cells??

Comment: The first cell that contains any. The excel sheets I'm getting the data from all have the values in different places, so I just need the first instance to get how many rows need to have data pulled from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with .find and .find is very inefficient, loop with IF, and, if you want to avoid a big OR do:

```
if instr("st1#st2#st3#...",cells(..,..)) & "#")>0 then
```

Cell value "Paul"

Match

```
MsgBox InStr("Peter#Paul#Ringo#", "Paul" & "#")
```

No Match

```
MsgBox InStr("Peter#Paul#Ringo#", "Pau" & "#")
```

No Match

```
MsgBox InStr("Peter#Paul#Ringo#", "Paul Mc" & "#")
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just have to do a loop with `If Or`then. Can't do `instr`, because I need a direct match. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, why can't you use instr with a direct match?

Comment: Doesn't `instr` check if the string is in the entire cell, instead of a direct match? There's a possibility that sheet will have cells that read `"'String1' More Text"` and also just `"String1"`, and I only want it to match if it's `"String1"`.

Comment: Well yes and no. :) In this case you're matching cell value(second arg) against the list of values (first arg). as long as you write in the first arg the exact match ("String1#String2#...") it will work. The # is to make sure that will not happen.

Comment: Would that be more efficient than an If Or? The last problem I'm having is getting it to search the entire workbook until it finds it.

Comment: I think that it will depend of the number of ors, I tested with 5 and a 1000000 loop - Instr took about 0.3 secs and 5 ors 0.4 secs

Comment: Alright. I imagine it's not a big deal if I have 14 or so then. Thanks! I'm using `UsedRange` with it, just gotta figure out how to get the location of the cell when it finds it.

Comment: ` .find is very inefficient, loop with IF,` <-- what? `.Find` is almost always WAY more efficient than iterating through an entire range...

Comment: we are talking about several different .Find (we need to match not one but several things) and yes you can be sure that .Find is very inefficient, about 5 times slower then application.match

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double for loop where the outer for loop will iterate though all of the cells and the inner for loop searches each cell for the strings you are look at and uses the .find function.  It will find the first occurance and you can do whatever you want.

set rng = [range you are searching] (assuming this is one column, can adjust code for 2d array by adding another for loop)
strings[] = array of your search strings

```
For i = 1 to rng.cells.count
    For j = 0 to strings.count
        found = instr(strings[j],rng.cells(i,1)
        If found >0 then
            'whatever you want to do
        Endif
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: That's what I've been doing so far, was just going to see if there was a faster, cleaner way to do so. There's about 14 `Or`s in the `if` statement.